# Unable to connect the internet after uninstalling NordVPN (20.04.1 LTS)

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, internet, vpn

I recently installed NordVPN on a machine with a dual-boot (Win10 + Ubuntu) and all was good until I tried to uninstall. At the point I lost the ability to connect the internet, not with the WiFi and not with the cable.
I had a long exchange of emails with their support team but they didn't help to solve the problem. In the end they just told that the problem is with my OS and they can't help me in any way. They made install and re-install the package a number of times, made me change my DNS servers, disable IPv6 and reset the NetworkManager. I'm not expert so I followed blondly their instructions.

I'm not in the position to simply re-install the OS as I would have done normally,  so I hope that someone can help to fix it.

Comment: The tech support from the company who software appears to have caused the problem can not help? Do not see how any one here could, I think it is re install time. Why can you not re install?

Comment: Yeah, can you believe it.. how shitty is that service??
Anyway why do you think no one could? I just think that people in customer service are not that much into Linux - I see there are quite a lot of questions here about connections problems that they are supposed to solve..  

Edit: It's a long story, trust me if I say that I can't re install..  :)

Comment: simple question did you reboot the system after that?

Comment: "I had a long exchange of emails with their support team but they didn't help to solve the problem."  --  Only a thousand times...  :)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

`sudo killall nordvpnd`

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

add/replace:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If you can't make the changes:

Overwrite the permission

`sudo chattr -i -a '/etc/resolv.conf'`

`sudo chmod ugo+w '/etc/resolv.conf'`

Then

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

now you can check with `ping -c2 google.com`

P.S.

I have used NordVPN in the past and they like to change the permissions of `resolv.conf` for some reason and after update or un-installation it messes up with the `resolv.conf`

Comment: Usually the reboot should have fixed it, if not try the above.

Comment: I would only add maybe remove the internet connection in nm-connection-editor (you have not said if ethernet or wireless though). and unplug, replug the cable back in to pick up a new connection.

" I'm not expert so I followed blondly their instructions." Of course blondly, it is Nordic VPN. /joke  .  I was very happy with their service and help responses.

Comment: no need to unplug the cable you can reload the network interface but if the permission of resolv.conf has been overwritten by NordVPN it won't help

Comment: Ok, I'll try and let you know! Thanks!!

Comment: Si I tried what you wrote. 
I had to overwrite the permission, replaced the nameserver and restarted the NetworkManager but still nothing, I've tried to give again the command 
"sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf" and this time it reads:
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53

Rebooted again but still no connection... I am lost..

Comment: try `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Comment: Hey thanks, 
I've tried. No output and no connections also after reboot.

Comment: can you ping google? ping -c2 google.com

Comment: Not really:
`ping: google.com: Temporärer Fehler bei der Namensauflösung`

It says Temporary name resolution error.

Comment: You have to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4` 
then restart network `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` and then ping google.

Comment: if that still didn't help try `sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient` and then `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`